# Cascade Delete for MySQL and ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, cascade, cascading-deletes

I have create simple asp.net (MVC4) web page with mysql database. There I have two tables (persons and orders), where table orders have FORIGN Key Persons_ID. I whant to create delete function, so, when I delete person from persons table, it will also delete all orders from order table for this person.

For creating models I have used ADO.NET and it create this two models for each tables:

persons.cs
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

```
namespace MvcMySQLTest1.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class person
    {
        public person()
        {
            this.orders = new HashSet<order>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Adress { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<order> orders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

orders.cs

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace MvcMySQLTest1.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class order
    {
        public int O_Id { get; set; }
        public int OrderNo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Persons_Id { get; set; }

        public virtual person person { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I have also create MainModel - like I container for both models above:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcMySQLTest1.Models
{
    public class MainModel 
    {

        public person Persons { get; set; }

        public order Orders { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Now for Cascade deleting I have try this - so when I delete Person, it will also delete all Orders for this Person in order table**, but this seems **not to work**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcMySQLTest1.Models
{
    public class MainModel : DbContext //added
    {

        public person Persons { get; set; }

        public order Orders { get; set; }

        //added  
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

        modelBuilder.Entity<orders>()
          .HasOptional(a => a.persons)
          .WithOptionalDependent()
          .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try something like this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<order>() 
    .HasRequired(a => a.person) 
    .WithMany(t => t.order) 
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.Persons_Id) 
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Or try to read more here [MSDN Cascade Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#CascadeDelete). May something can help from there

Comment: tnx for response, I will try it as soon as possible. But I give you vote up.